# Downloaded page size vs. browsed page size

Tags: image, browser, resize

I am having some speed problems on my site, and I noticed that when I saved the web page on disk it is around 7 MB. However, the same big images seem to be scaled on web page. 
So, basically the question is "Does the user browsing a web page download all resources of that page? Or do they resources get optimized and scaled first and then sent to the user?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they download it all by default (in some cases, 'smart' browsers shrink the data if the user enable 'data saving mode'). You need to generate thumbnails for your big images.

You can check your website optimization with [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=stackoverflow.com)